# This site can't be reached

Tags: networking, wifi, internet

My Raspberry Pi is successfully connected to internet but my chromium browser is showing the error `"This site can't be reached"`. [image]

Comment: Are you using WiFi or Ethernet? What is the output of `ifconfig` or `ip addr`? As the error message in Chromium is about _Name Resolution_ have you tried `dig google.com`, `whois google.com` or another website in the browser? What is the output from `traceroute 8.8.8.8` (you may want to obscure the first few lines from your reply as it will contain your public IP address)?

Comment: the output of `ip route show` would also be useful.

Comment: How do you determine that the RasPi is successfully connected to internet? Does other sites are reachable? Can you ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: And if you will post the logs, please remove the picture too. There's no useful info in it.